# Odd behavior in a recursive f# function

Tags: recursion, f#, integer-overflow

I'm trying a naive recursive function in f#:

```
let rec fact n  =
    if n > 0 then
        n * fact (n - 1)
    else 
        1
```

For small arguments, it works fine, however, if you pass a big enough number, it fails in an odd way:

```
> fact 41;;
val it : int = 0

> fact 25;;
val it : int = 2076180480

> fact 26;;
val it : int = -1853882368
```

I guess some sort of overflow is going on, but shouldn't I get an error???

Comment: No, F# doesn't check for overflow by default. You need to import overflow checking operators via `open Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.Checked`

Comment: Or use `BigInteger`. In general the int behavior in many languages is inconsistent. In most language `1/0` gives an exception which makes sense because the result can't fit in the value range of int but neither does it in your case when you get an overflow so it would make sense with an exception. But it has "always" been liks this and lots of program uses int overflows as a feature not a bug.

Comment: if any of you can turn the into an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you!